# How to project raster and observation points with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-raster

He all!
I'm new in R world and I think that this will be a stupid error:
I would like to project a raster representing my "study area" adding observations take from `rgbif`.

First, I've take specie observations in the "study area" using a polygon:

```r
wkt <- 'POLYGON((14.022120 41.583456,13.928857 41.610301,13.607180 41.789949,13.645924 42.021854,13.779864 42.029311,14.035472 41.823996,14.066175 41.751961,14.057895 41.614899,14.022120 41.583456))'

Picus_viridis <- occ_data(scientificName = "Picus viridis", geometry = wkt, return = "data", limit = 1999)
Picus_viridis<-Picus_viridis$data
```

Second, I've upload the raster, cropped it to the extension of interest and assigned a projection:

```r
elev <- raster("data/gtopo30/gtopo30.tif")
elev_park <- crop(elev, extent(13.398953, 14.235655, 41.402820, 42.064252))

projection(elev_park) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Than I've tried to plot the raster with the observation points using `ggplot` but R said me the there is an error:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(elev_park, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Picus_viridis$decimalLongitude, y = Picus_viridis$decimalLatitude))
```

> Errore: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Does anyone know were the problem is?

---

raster GTOPO30:

```
> elev_park
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 84, 112, 9408  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333334, 0.008333334  (x, y)
extent     : 13.30001, 14.23334, 41.40001, 42.10001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : gtopo30 
values     : 16, 2689  (min, max)
```

Comment: it will be easier to help if you provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It looks as if you might be missing the `data` argument to `ggplot`?

Comment: also, mapping should be the 1st argument int the geom_raster.

Answer (score 1):

Without your dataset, I cannot confirm if this will all work, but the general structure of `ggplot` usage is:

- In your `ggplot()` call, you should supply the dataset and the mapping.  You don't *have* to do this, but it's generally a good idea unless you're using pipe commands (`%>%`) or something similar.  Your base `mapping=` is almost always provided there too.  Think of this function as "creating your basic plot without the data at all".
- All `geom_` functions (to my knowledge) have an argument setup that starts with `mapping=`, then `data=`, then other arguments.  This means if you do not explicitly declare the structure, the first argument will be applied to `mapping=`.  This is why your `geom_raster(elev_park,...)` is going to throw an error.
- It's generally best practice to send the geoms `data` as a dataset and mappings as the names of your columns--not naming the vector.  So, instead of `x=my_dataset$column1`, you would set it up as `data=my_dataset` and `mapping=aes(x=column1...)`.

With that being said, my suggested revision that should give you something is below.  This assumes that `elev_park$x` and `elev_park$y` exist.  If not, replace `x=` and `y=` mapping with the correct column name (unquoted).

```
ggplot(elev_park, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_raster() +     # mapping not needed.  It's passed from ggplot()
  geom_point(         # should be explicit when setting mapping and data
    data=Picus_viridis,
    mapping=aes(x=decimalLongitude, y =decimalLatitude)
  )
```